# How to change size of a seaborn barplot?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I want to adjust the size of my barplot to fit my data well.

I tried:

```
ax = sns.barplot(x=b1_df2.score/(-2), y='CountryCode', hue='question_code', data=b1_df2.loc[b1_df2.answer == 'Very widespread'])
plt.xlabel("Questions")
plt.ylabel("%")
plt.title("Title (very widespread)")
plt.figure(figsize=(50,10))
```

No effect seen no matter of the figsize parameters.

Comment: mention `plt.figure(...)` before ax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the size afterwards, do:

```
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(50,10)
```

or:

```
ax.figure.set_size_inches(50,10)
```